# Computational and mathematical physics Stationary action principle

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, computational-mathematics, mathematica, euler-lagrange-equation

This is a computational and mathematical physics problem that has me frustrated. Been trying for a few hours to no avail. Any help is appreciated

The functional is of the form:

> $ I\left [ f \right ]=\int_{0}^{1}F\left [ f,f',x \right ]dx=\int_{0}^{1}\left ( \frac{1}{2}f'\left ( x \right )^{2} +\frac{1}{2}xf\left ( x \right )^{2}+xf\left ( x \right )\right )$

I am asked to check that

$f_{\alpha}\left ( x \right )=\alpha x\left ( 1-x \right )$ satisfy the boundary condition $f_{\alpha}\left ( 0 \right )=f_{\alpha}\left ( 1 \right )=0$

Indeed, it does.

Now, I am asked to plot the exact solution along with $f_{\alpha}$ for various $\alpha$.

I don't understand what this exact solution is but it could be some non-unique trial solution that satisfy the boundary condition. Any clarification at this point might be helpful.
Using Mathematica, the various value of $\alpha$ for the function $f_{\alpha}$ is
[image]

Then, I am now tasked to compute the stationary value of the functional

> $I\left [ f_{\alpha}\left ( x \right ) \right ]$.

The stationary action of any functional I is really just a function f(x) such that the functional I equals to zero.
This is equivalent to solving for the Euler-Lagrange equation which is

> $\frac{\partial I}{\partial f}-\frac{d}{dt}\left (  \frac{\partial I}{\partial }\dot{f}\right )=0$
>
> This is $\ddot{f}\left ( x \right )+xf\left ( x \right )+x=0$

Mathematica tells me there is no analytical solution to this ODE (weird).

This gives

> $\ddot{f_{\alpha}\left ( x \right )}+xf_{\alpha}\left ( x \right )+x=0$

The above ODE has the same form as the one I made the claim that Mathematica has no analytical solution.
Then what?

Edit:

[image: The orange plot represents the exact] solution plot (of airy function) and the blue plot represents a 'trial' solution $f_\alpha(x)$. Geometrically, the values for which the trial solution approximates the exact solution is $\alpha$=-0.5...
We now have the trial solution $f_\alpha=-0.5(x)$

In computing the action functional of the trial solution and determining the values for $\alpha$,
$\alpha=-10/21$ and $\alpha=0$. We ignore the trivial solution.

Plotting the trial solution $f_\alpha=-10/21(x)$ and $f_\alpha=-0.5(x)$:
[image]

Which seems like a pretty good approximation.

Edit:

For a two bifurcation parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$ case:

For a more general function: $f_\alpha,\beta \left ( x \right )=x\left ( 1-x \right )\left ( \alpha+\beta x \right )$ has two bifurcation parameters.

As usual the boundary condition $f_\alpha,\beta \left ( 0 \right )$=$f_\alpha,\beta \left ( 1 \right )$=0

In computing the stationary values of the functional $I\left [ f_\alpha,\beta \left ( x \right ) \right ]$, it is easy to show that the
the values are

> $\frac{7\alpha^{2}}{40}+\frac{37\alpha \beta}{21}+\frac{\alpha}{12}+\frac{39 \beta^{2}}{560}+\frac{\beta}{20}$

as verified by Mathematica.

[image]

Here is where things starts getting mysterious:

In using the `Solve` function on Mathematica, there are two $\alpha$ and two $\beta$ values. How do I proceed from here.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled as to what they want regarding the 'exact solution.' However, if they ask for $I[f_\alpha]$ then I don't see a need to use Euler-Lagrange; one should just plug the given form of $f_\alpha(x)$ into the functional, evaluate the resulting integral. One can then find the value of $\alpha$ for which $I[f_\alpha]$ is stationary.

Comment: Also, your statement of the Euler-Lagrange equations is a bit off: It should be $\displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial f}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{f}}=0$. I also find that the resulting ODE is $f''(x)=x f(x)+x$ i.e. $f''(x)$ is on the opposite side. Finally, Mathematica can solve the ODE subject to the boundary condition, but the solution is in terms of Airy functions and is not very helpful. If you just want to plot it, though, then `NDSolve` is entirely sufficient.

Comment: @Semiclassical, exactly that. He is asked to find the stationary for that uniparametric family of functions. The plot is for values of $L[f_\alpha]$ wrt some values of $\alpha$, maybe.

Comment: @Semiclassical What is the variational solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what the question is getting at.

Below, I plotted the exact solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation $f''(x) - xf(x)-x = 0$ with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ in blue.

I also plotted the function $f_\alpha(x)$ with $\alpha = -\frac 5 {21}$ in pink.

[image]

*Notice that $f_{\alpha = - \frac 5 {21}}(x)$ is a fairly good approximation to the exact solution $f(x)$!*

So why is this the case? Well, $f(x)$ is the exact solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation, so it is the function that minimises $I[f]$ among the class of all functions obeying the boundary conditions $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.

Unfortunately, as you have noticed, it's very hard to work with the true solution $f(x)$, as we can't write down a simple analytical formula for it. Indeed, I had to calculate $f(x)$ numerically using NDSolve (as @Semiclassical suggested).

However, since we expect the true solution $f(x)$ to be some sort of convex "U-shaped" function, it's reasonable to guess that $f(x)$ can be roughly approximated by $f_\alpha(x) = \alpha x (1-x)$ for some value of $\alpha$. Since $f(x)$ minimises $I[f]$, we expect that the best approximation to $f(x)$ will be given by choosing the value of $\alpha$ such that $I[f_\alpha]$ is a small as possible.

You should now check (by explicitly plugging in the expression for $f_\alpha(x)$ into the expression for $I$) that $I[f_\alpha] =  \frac 1 {12} \alpha + \frac {7}{40} \alpha^2$ for any given $\alpha$. You should then verify that the choice of $\alpha$ that makes $I[f_\alpha]$ as small as possible is $\alpha = - \frac 5 {21}$ (plotted in pink above).

Finally, the value of $I[f_{\alpha = \frac{5}{21}}]$  is $ -\frac {5}{504}$, which again you should check. This is an approximation (more specifically, an upper bound) for $I[f]$ evaluated on the true solution $f(x)$.

Comment: I did an edit to reflect my attempt. 
For the case where a trial function has 2 bifurcation parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there are two $beta$ values and two $\alpha$ values. How can this be reconciled?

Comment: @Mathematicing Could you please tell me the form of your trial function with $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Maybe I can investigate...

Comment: Let me include it in the original post.

Comment: @Mathematicing Okay! By the way, it's a good idea to change the plot range on mathematica to {x,0,1}. (because we don't care about other $x$). Also, $\alpha = 0$ is not a solution - there is no trivial solution!

Comment: Interesting, Mathematica actually does return $\alpha=0$ to be one solution...

Comment: @Mathematicing Oh I see what you've done! You were solving $I[f_\alpha] = 0$. (which gives $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha = 10/21$). But you are meant to solve $dI[f_\alpha]/d\alpha = 0$ (giving $\alpha = 5/21$).

Comment: @Mathematicing Remember, the solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation is not a function that sets $I[f]$ to zero. It is a function that _minimises_ $I[f]$.

Comment: @Mathematicing And presumably this will resolve your problem with the $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I take it that since the negative $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values are ignore, I need proceed only with the positive values, right? Btw, edit made to OP.

Comment: @Mathematicing Could you please tell me what your $f_{\alpha, \beta}$ is? You should be solving $\frac{\partial I[f_{\alpha, \beta}]}{\partial \alpha} = \frac{\partial I[f_{\alpha, \beta}]}{\partial \beta} = 0$. Any solution is valid, regardless of whether $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive or negative. Don't try to solve $I[f_{\alpha, \beta}] = 0$ - this is not the right thing to do!!!

Comment: It is $x(1-x)(\alpha+\beta x)$.

Comment: @Mathematicing Yeah, so I got one solution to $\partial I / \partial \alpha = \partial I / \partial \beta = 0$: $\alpha = -987/6247$, $\beta =  - 994/6247$. You may like to plot this solution and compare to your exact solution. But make sure you set the axis range to $0 \leq x \leq 1$, so that you can see things clearly!

Comment: Thank you Kenny. There should be enough leads for reconciliation. Nice credentials btw.

Comment: @Mathematicing Cool, and if you have any more questions, feel free to ask! :)

Comment: Given that $\alpha\approx \beta$ one can evidently also take the model solution to be $f_{\alpha,\alpha}$; this makes the algebra simpler without making the variational solution much worse at all. More precisely, when $\alpha,\beta$ are as in Kenny Wong's comment one gets $I[f_{\alpha,\beta}]=-0.010561069...$. When $\alpha=\beta=-16/101$ one instead gets $I[f_{\alpha,\beta}]=-0.0105611056$, so they agree up until the 8th digit. (By contrast, the best $f_\alpha$ solution gives $I[f]=-0.0099$ which is not nearly as good.)

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks, that's an excellent point!